# Activity with fragment and another Activity return null on onActvityResult

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

**ActivityOne** -> Contain FragmentOne and I added method onActivityResult

**FragmentOne** -> contain recyclerView and on item click startActivityForResult going to ActivityTwo

**ActivityTwo** -> for item details in the recyclerView in FragmentOne

ActivityOne get null data onActivityResult

**Code:
ActivityOne**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Utils.showToast("intent receive");
    if (requestCode==1111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        int position =(int) data.getExtras().get("position");
        Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: "+ position);
    }
}
```

**Code:FragmentOne**

```
   Intent i = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("id", id);
            bundle.putInt("position",position);
            i.putExtras(bundle);  
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(i,1111);
```

**Code:ActivityTwo**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (hasChanges){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("position",position);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    }
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `onBackPressed()` as.You just finished activity without send result back. 
And one more thing in this case `super.onBackPressed()` will do same thing as finish.So just call one .

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (hasChanges){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("position",position);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```